# get saved data from files after writing into them without closing the program

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

I have code of form below:

```
func1()
{
    fstream stud("student", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    stud << "sameer";
    stud.close();
}

func2()
{
    string name;
    fstream stud("student", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::app);
    stud >> name;
    stud.close();
}
```

here both functions are in same program but even if `func1` has `stud` closed, on opening  the file in `func2` the changes are not reflected.

Comment: Works here, can you provide a real test case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `fstream::app` from your reader.  With `fstream::app`, the file pointer starts at the end of the file, so you just read an empty string.

Comment: fstream::app coz i have to append data at the end of file suggest any thing else to allow appending data then... i am just concerned that what ever i write to the file it is still available for input,but with above method i am able write a data but not able read the same data even after closing file stream.

Comment: You have many options.  Setting `fstream::app` on writing but *not* on reading will solve your immediate problem.  If you insist on `fstream::app` on reading, then use `seekg` and `tellg` to move around the file to where the data is.